# Add event listener to a button on a Page Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In `content.js`, I am trying to add an event listener to a button on the page but I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
```

I have tried to put it in `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',afterDOMLoaded);` but `DOMContentLoaded` never fires in the `content.js` script. How can I add an event listener to a button on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You should show how your content.js is executed.

Maybe, the page has already `DOMContentLoaded` when your script is inejcted.
The injection timing can be specified in manifest file.
If your manifest file is the following, your content.js is injected **immediately after the `window.onload` event fires**, that is after `DOMContentLoaded`.
Refer https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/.

```
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["https://*/*"],
  "run_at": "document_idle",
  "js": ["content.js"]
}
```

If your manifest is like the above, you do not need event listener, just write the code in content.js script instead.